# Serve an ical feed with Flask

Tags: python, flask, icalendar

I've got a small flask website, and I want to serve an ical feed from it.
I've already created an ics-file, which gets frequently updated, however I can't figure out how to serve it from the website.
I've tried doing it through `Response` and `serve_file`, but they just display the text in the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the the correct [content disposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) header of the response. In your case the header would be something like the following:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=calender.ics;
```

In your Flask route your code should look something like the following:

```
from flask import make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

# ...

@app.route('/calendar/')
def calendar():

    #  Get the calendar data
    _calendar = make_calendar()

    #  turn calendar data into a response
    response = make_response(_calendar)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=calendar.ics"
    return response
```